# nginx location to serve multiple endpoints

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i need this location block to route to two different backend endpoints

```
location ~* /zones/
```

it must have logic that enables these rewrites to be successful:

```
/zones/appinfo.axd >>> /zones/appinfo.axd
/zones/api/v2/zones >>> /api/v2/zones
```

here is what i have currently:

```
location ~* /zones/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    rewrite ^ /api/v2/zones break;
    proxy_pass http://zone_api;
}
```

however it's only working for the second rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
location ~ ^/zones(/api.+)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://zone_api$1;
}

location /zones {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://zone_api;
}
```

The first `location` uses regex to capture the string after `/zones` part info a variable, and then that variable is used for `proxy_pass` destination.

The second location is a simple prefix match, which passes URL paths as-is to the `proxy_pass`.

Comment: awesome! the ^/zones(/api.+)$ bit is what i needed.

Comment: **/zones/api/v2/zones?page=2&page_size=200** does not appear to work though. i get a 200, but the api returns **"page_number":1,"page_size":10**

Comment: You might need to use `proxy_pass http://zone_api$1$is_args$args` instead. If that doesn't help, there is something odd in the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a location and alias for each individual URL.

```
location /zones/appinfo.axd {
  alias /zones/appinfo.axd;
}
location /zones/api/v2/zones {
  alias /api/v2/zones;
}
```

Note this is for the exact URLs you specified. You didn't include any wildcards or subfolder requirements, just those exact URLs.